# Is there a way of pushing messages to rabbitmq with celery without having the task defined on the code

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I need to separate my app stack to have web and worker as separate micro service i.e they both run in different infrastructure and both have different repository .

The blocker am getting is how am adding message into the queue i.e task.add.delay(a,b) this means the task add should be in web , I can easily replace the way am pushing messages to rabbitmqp by using pika python package but then I will loose other functionality such as chain i.e chain = add(a,b) | send_result() ; chain()

Is there a way of pushing messages to rabbitmq with celery without having the task defined on the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `send_task`:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task

This would allow you to do something like `app.send_task('tasks.add', args=[1,2])`

If you need to chain tasks, you should use signatures (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.signature):

```
from celery import signature, chain

sig1 = signature('tasks.add', args=[1,2])
sig2 = signature('tasks.add', args=[4,9])
result = chain(sig1, sig2)()
```

Comment: that works suppose I want to call the tasks in a chain eg. `chain = task.add(a,b) | task.send_result(); chain()`    how do I do that with send_task method